# Manwha that has a sect called Beiyu. The guy gets a system that rewards him when he gives things to disciples. It has a demon dog and a wolf demon

Tags: story-identification, manga

The first disciple is a sword guy who hates the master and does not believe in him at all in the beginning. Later, he does, but still... The guy gets two disciples: him (he has to trick him to accept him as his master) and a small girl who is an empress. He gets to ride in a weird tank that is made out of dragons. He receives rewards every time he gives something to the disciples. The first thing he gets is bread from someone, since he is quite poor at the beginning.

It's not *The Most Generous Master Ever*.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh! It must be "**I Upgrade by Rewarding Apprentices**."

There is Beiyu, a demon dog, a wolf demon, and disciples including a sword-wielding character and a young girl who is an empress.

He was riding in a tank made out of dragons and receiving rewards for each item given to the disciples, starting with  bread because he was poor​.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should specify which chapters these things appear in, or include some frames that show them.

Comment: Note to upvoters; I've skimmed through nearly half of the named webcomic, and found only a sword-wielding cultivator with disciples.  The bit about hating his master is not a match.  He does not have a male disciple in the first two, and he isn't tricking people to become disciples.  He does get rewards for gifts, but the bit about bread is _also_ not a match.  I still haven't found any demons (dog, wolf, or otherwise) no dragons and the sect is not "Beiyu."

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect.  Other than "a sword-wielding character" (duh; cold-reading anyone?) and a system that rewards the protagonist for giving gifts to his disciples, every single detail in this answer is wrong.  (Note that I've now actually skimmed the entire series to date, so this is definite.)